# Recovering emmc memory

Tags: raspbian, data-recovery

I used an odroid-xu4 as a personal web server for about a year. Yesterday, I rebooted it, and it never started again. I thought it was the board, but If I plug the emmc memory ([ref](http://ameridroid.com/products/32gb-emmc-5-0-module-xu3-linux)) into my computer, I get this error:
`mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising MMC card`
For what I've seen, it's probably broken. So I have two questions:

Can it be recovered?

If it was a malware (like a ransom-ware), I'll still be able to mount the emmc, right?

Answer (score 0):

It probably can't be recovered in a cost-effective way. If it was ransom-ware, you would be able to read the MMC, yes; so it's unlikely to be that.

Comment: How much do you think it can cost?

Comment: I'd guess several hundred euros if you ask a recovery company to do it; perhaps just some time and knowledge if you can go to a local hacklab.